# jquery, change order of append tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have below code :

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="#">
</div>
```

I append `span` to this `div` tag:

```
$('div#test').append('<span>123123</span>');
```

this result :

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="#">
    <span>123123<span>
</div>
```

but I want get `span` first , like this :

```
<div id="test">
   <span>123123<span>
   <img src="#">
</div>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: prepend instead of append

Comment: Your HTML is not valid at the moment. You have an unclosed `<div>` and a never opened `<li>`. Try fixing that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('div#test').prepend('<span>123123</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prepend();` to change the order.

Answer (score 1):

[`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) is easier to remember. Then there's its counterpart [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/). And then there's the previously mentioned [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend) and its opposite [`.prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo).

Plain JavaScript has [`.before()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/before), [`.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend), [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), and my favorite [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). `.insertAdjacentHTML()` is like `.innerHTML` that can insert `htmlString` at 4 different positions in relation to an element.

> **Signature:**
>    *DOMObject*`.insertAdjacentHTML(`**Position**`,`*htmlString*`)`
>   **Position:**
>   "beforebegin" `<div>` **"afterbegin"** `...` "beforeend" `</div>`"afterend"

```js
$('#test1 img').before('<span>123123</span>');

$('<span>123123</span>').insertBefore('#test2 img');

$('#test3').prepend('<span>123123</span>');

$('<span>123123</span>').prependTo('#test4');

document.querySelector('#test5 img').before(document.createElement('SPAN').textContent = '123123');

var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.textContent = '123123';
document.querySelector('#test6').insertBefore(span, document.querySelector('#test6 img'));

document.querySelector('#test7').prepend(document.createElement('SPAN').textContent = '123123');

document.querySelector('#test8').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<span>123123</span>');
```

```html
<div id="test1">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test2">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test3">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test4">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test5">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test6">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test7">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>

<div id="test8">
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png" width='50'>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```